# Prevent URL being stored to browser history

Tags: url, xhtml, iframe, browser-history, strict

I need to open a popup window to a url with certain parameters. The parameters contain information that I would like to prevent from showing up in the browser history. The url points to a 3rd party site and I can't affect the way those parameters are transferred to them (can't use POST for example).

Currently I have worked around this so that I have a page on our server that loads the content of the third party page to an iframe and this seems to work.

However, I was wondering if there are any other ways of doing this and are they maybe somehow better or worse? Javascript or something? The negative side of this iframe thing is that it is not XHTML Strict compliant, which is something we are aiming for.

There are other similar questions here but I couldn't find a good answer.

Edit: Apparently this does not work as expected in IE. It might be that I still keep the solution for another reason, but it would be nice to know if there is a "bulletproof" solution.

Comment: Hiding it from history doesn't prevent it from being logged everywhere along the path of the request by third parties. Passing sensitive data like that is a bad idea.

Comment: @Radomir: Well, obviously, yes. Like I said, I can't affect that. However other measures have been taken to prevent the usage of that data. This prevention is an additional control.

Comment: Here is a Mozilla add-on for doing just this. It was exactly what I was thinking of, but had to read through ALL of their history related Add-Ons before I discovered this. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/delete-site-history/?src=search